# Cannot create ActiveX component VB.net Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have been using this piece of code without error for the last few weeks but when I returned to it this week I keep getting this error.
"Cannot create ActiveX Component"

```
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Start Excel yourself to see if it still operates correctly.  That also tends to heal any registry damage.

Comment: @HansPassant I can open excel no problem